# Linq updates extra rows

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq

I'm using vb.net entities to access data in a sql server 2014 database.

I have a function which receives an "owner" object and if the owner has multiple current entries in the table, it's supposed to update the older entries to have a status of previous.

```vb
Private Shared Sub CreatePreviousOwners(currentOwners As List(Of Owner), prop As compProp)
Dim names = prop.GetVendorsNames()
Using context = New GovernContext()
            Dim sameOwners = From v In currentOwners
                             Where names.Any(Function(o) o.Na_Id = v.Na_Id)
                             Select v
           If sameOwners.Count > 0 Then
                For Each owner In sameOwners
                    'Find all entries prior to the newest
                    Dim prevOwner = From p In context.Owner
                                    Where p.Status = "O" _
                                    And owner.Na_Id = p.Na_Id _
                                    And p.P_Id = prop.p_id _
                                    And p.As_Of_Date < owner.As_Of_Date 
                                    Select p
                    'Update all found entries to previous
                    For Each own As Owner In prevOwner
                        own.Status = "P"
                    Next
                Next
                context.SaveChanges()
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Here's a small dataset:

```
p_id    na_id   AS_OF_DATE              status
596     589494  2008-09-10 00:00:00.000 O
596     589494  2017-08-02 00:00:00.000 O
596     1453364 2017-08-02 00:00:00.000 P
```

When I step through the code, there is only one entry in the prevOwner sequence.

When I run the sql profiler to view the linq query, the update statement is missing any as_of_date condition. 
Here's the query from the profiler:

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[Owner]
SET [Status] = @0
WHERE (([P_Id] = @1) AND ([Na_Id] = @2))
',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 int,@2 int',@0=N'P',@1=596,@2=589494
```

Is my sql malformed, or am I missing something?

Comment: What status changes would you expect and why?

Comment: are you 100% sure owner.as_of_data isnt nothing?

Comment: @TToni If a property is sold, a new record is created in the owner table with the status set to 'O'.  The only status change i expect here is that the top row have the status set to 'P'.  Instead, Both 'O' statuses are being set to 'P'

Comment: @gh9 Yes, i'm sure.  It's one of the values that makes a data row unique in the table.

Comment: Does a table have a primary key? What is it?

Comment: @Alex there's no key in the db itself.  In the entity, the key is on the p_id and na_id.

Comment: @Rolan - how do you expect Linq and SQL to uniquely identify a row then? Why do you then complain that `AS_OF_DATE` is missing as you did not define it as part of your key.

Comment: @Alex I thought that it would use the sequence to determine which rows to update (hence the foreach in the sequence), and so the as_of_date condition would be included in the update.

Comment: Because I hadn't looked at it, and didn't know to look for it.  Perhaps I'll see if adding the as_of_date as part of the entity key will help.

Comment: What do you mean by sequence? If you mean position inside a list, then no this not how it all works! Relational databases never* take into account row positions. (* there are tricks to simulate that e.g. `ROW_NUMBER()` but I digress). That is why you have a concept of primary keys in database tables.

Comment: Every query in linq is a sequence (or that's what Bill Wagner deems to be the proper terminology).  Frankly, the database itself has little to do with how linq creates queries to be run on it.  Regardless, position would have no effect on the query.

Comment: @Rohan, not sure what you are trying to say here. I hope I explained clearly enough, where you problem lays: as_of_date is not part of your key so it will not be used in a database query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be expecting too much from Entity Framework. When EF updates database records it's always *one record at a time*. It doesn't do batch updates.

Here's what happens in your code (which I slightly modified):

```vb
Private Shared Sub CreatePreviousOwners(currentOwners As List(Of Owner), prop As compProp)
    Dim names = prop.GetVendorsNames()
    Using context = New GovernContext()

        'Runs a SQL SELECT query and creates a list of owners
        Dim sameOwners = (From v In currentOwners
                         Where names.Any(Function(o) o.Na_Id = v.Na_Id)
                         Select v).ToList()

        For Each owner In sameOwners
            'Find all entries prior to the newest

            'Runs another SQL SELECT query
            Dim prevOwner = From p In context.Owner
                            Where p.Status = "O" _
                            And owner.Na_Id = p.Na_Id _
                            And p.P_Id = prop.p_id _
                            And p.As_Of_Date < owner.As_Of_Date 
                            Select p
            'Update all found entries to previous

            'Executes the SELECT query and loops through the results
            For Each own As Owner In prevOwner

                'Adds a modified entry to EF's change tracker
                own.Status = "P"

            Next
        Next

        'Runs update statements for each modified entry in the change tracker
        context.SaveChanges()

    End Using
End Sub
```

As you see, at the time EF is ready for updating the database it doesn't have any knowledge as to how the modified entries were collected. The updates could be done much smarter, i.e. in statements that update batches of `Owner`s that satisfy the condition `p.As_Of_Date < owner.As_Of_Date`, but collecting data and updating them are totally independent operations in EF.

That's why you only see UPDATE statements in which one record is identified by its primary key. You may see *many* of them.

There are third-party libraries that enable batch (or bulk) updates, inserts, and deletes.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Gert.  Before Alex and yourself pointed it out, I didn't realize that EF used the primary key to run the update statement.  I'll have to read a book about the EF architecture (any suggestions?), so that I don't expect the wrong things from it.  Thanks again!